# Understanding the radius of convergence of a power series

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

The source of a recent torrent of confusion for me  has to do with the following equation:

$$ R = |x-x_0| < \lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}| $$

I have trouble interpreting this, and even more trouble trying to articulate my confusions. My confusions are three-fold: a confusion with the derivation process I'll bring up, what exactly is going on with the bit $\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}| $, and what the equation essentially says itself. If this is too much for one question, I'll split it up but any effort to answer any of these for me would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to let me know if any of my poor attempts to articulate my confusions need some re-explaining.

### Confusion with derivation

My first question has to do with me deriving the equation wrong at first but not understanding why.

$$|x-x_0| \lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| < 1 \implies Convergent$$

From here, instead of dividing both sides by $\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}| $, I divided both sides by $|x-x_0|$.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|  < \frac{1}{|x-x_0|}$$

And then, finally:

$$R = \lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}| < |x-x_0|$$

What did I do here that is wrong? Why am I meant to divide each side by the limit term instead?

### Understanding $\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$ and what the equation itself implies

Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$  has a limit operator, it must mean $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ can be represented in terms of $n$, however, $a_n$ came from $b_n=a_n(x-x_0)^n$ and similarly for $a_{n+1}$. Since $a_n$ is defined in this way, I have trouble imagining I can express $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ in such a way that I actually *can* evaluate the limit. For example, for the first term of $b_n$, starting at $n=0$, $b_0 = a_0(x-x_0)^0$. $a_0$ here is clearly some constant term. $a_0$ wouldn't be a constant term if it could be expressed in terms of $n$, so what's this limit operator going to do if $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ can't be expressed in terms of $n$? Hopefully what I'm getting at is making *some* sense.

And, to be honest, I'm not even exactly sure how translate this equation for $R$ into concise English. To me, with my mistaken interpretation, it's saying that if $\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}| $ is larger than a specified $x$ and $x_0$ value's difference, the series is divergent, and convergent if the opposite is true.  I've done the ratio test before to test convergence, and what will end up happening is having a function of $x$ = L, and the range of values $x$ can take will determine whether the function of $x$ is less or greater than $1$ and thus if the sequence is divergent or convergent. However, I don't get any of this information, personally, from looking at the equation here.

Comment: I believe it should be$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|,\quad|x-x_0|<R$$

Comment: The explanaton for this is simply that this is a limit comparison test to the geometric series.